# Line Chart with multiple colors for single line and multiple icons

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, report, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

need a Line chart as below that is filtered by Country->Customers->MachineType->MachineModel->Parts.

The Chart represents Consumed Material (In Tons) of Machines in Y-Axis and X-Axis is over time (Year-Months-Day).

My data is coming from a ML model that stores value for past 3 months and next 365 days.

1. How can I show the actual and predicted value in the same line with different colors? I can't use two lines to represent this.
2. How can I display multiple (around 100) icons ( Represented as Xs in below Picture) on the same line to represent another field value maintenance dates of Parts.

[image]

Comment: *I can't use two lines to represent this.* - Why?  Would it not be useful to highlight where the actuals and projections switch over in the chart?

Comment: It would also be very useful if you could add some source data and your model structure to your question, as any solution relies heavily on this information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this quite easily with a single dataset and a single line if you get the dataset right.

I've mocked up a small sample of data using the following...

This assumes two tables, one with material use and another with maintenance days

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(DateStamp date, Amount int)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
    ('2021-01-01', 10),
    ('2021-01-02', 11),
    ('2021-01-03', 12),
    ('2021-01-04', 14),
    ('2021-01-05', 16),
    ('2021-01-06', 18),
    ('2021-01-07', 20),
    ('2021-01-08', 21),
    ('2021-01-09', 22),
    ('2021-01-10', 23),
    ('2021-01-11', 24),
    ('2021-01-12', 25),
    ('2021-01-13', 26)

DECLARE @m TABLE(DateStamp date)

INSERT INTO @m VALUES
    ('2021-01-01'),
    ('2021-01-02'),
    ('2021-01-06'),
    ('2021-01-07')


SELECT t.*, CASE WHEN m.DateStamp IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as Maintenance
    FROM @t t 
        LEFT JOIN @m m on t.DateStamp = m.DateStamp
```

Using this as my dataset query I get the following data returned.

[image]

Now all I did was add a line chart with amount as the value and datestamp as the category group.

I then clicked the series line and changed the following properties...

Color

```
=IIF(Fields!DateStamp.Value <= Today(), "Blue", "Red")
```

MarkerType

```
=IIF(Fields!Maintenance.Value=1, "Diamond", Nothing)
```

... and finally set the maker size to 15pt for clarity in this example.

[image]

This gave me the following output

[image]